# How to parse this and get specific content

Tags: php

I have this data in a field of my database:

```
a:4:{i:15;s:0:"";i:26;s:0:"";i:33;s:0:"";i:1004;a:1:{s:12:"Special Hash";s:33:"1b44dxrLsCgKQiiVNMRVN5rmfXg84FEds";}}
```

I need to get this from it:

```
1b44dxrLsCgKQiiVNMRVN5rmfXg84FEds
```

(s:33 which is size might vary in different tables for example it can be s:34)

Already Tried:

```
$all=json_decode($this);
$hash=$all['Special Hash'];
$hash=$all->{'Special Hash']};
```

But no success

### Edit:

Thanks to the first answer from Terr (edited by Hanky 웃 Panky), i was able to get data by:

```
echo unserialize($mydata)['1004']['Special Hash'];
```

Comment: Ara you can mark their answer as accepted, that will be an even better note of thanks :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yes of course, as soon as i'm able (in 4 min)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is not JSON, but a PHP-serialized array using [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You can get access to the original array by putting that string through [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$string='a:4:{i:15;s:0:"";i:26;s:0:"";i:33;s:0:"";i:1004;a:1:{s:12:"Special Hash";s:33:"1b44dxrLsCgKQiiVNMRVN5rmfXg84FEds";}}';
print_r(unserialize($string));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [15] => 
    [26] => 
    [33] => 
    [1004] => Array
        (
            [Special Hash] => 1b44dxrLsCgKQiiVNMRVN5rmfXg84FEds
        )

)
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/qnBLPkhn)**

Comment: Oops I made edits to your answer to make it more effective thinking you are a new user and you spotted the issue well and I wanted to help you go along. Turns out you are an old user :) Sorry if you disliked the edit you can roll it back.

Comment: No problem! This illustrates the answer perfectly :)